# Ruby script to match and replace double quotes to single quotes on PHP files

Tags: php, regex, ruby

I'm trying to code a **ruby script** to replace double quotes to single quotes in **PHP** files when there's no parsing happening, need some help with the regex seeing that I'm still trying to learn it. Got something like this for string interpolation matching: `\"([^\$].*?)\"` but it still match patterns with $ in it.

### Example

How it's supposed to work

Before running the script:

```
// Normal string
$first = "some value";
// With var concatenation:
$second = "first var value is " . $first . "!";
// With var interpolation:
$third = "first var value is $first!";
// Arrays
$arr["fourth"] = $first;
```

Example after running the script:

```
// Normal string
$first = 'some value';
// With var concatenation:
$second = 'first var value is ' . $first . '!';
// With var interpolation:
$third = "first var value is $first!";
// Arrays
$arr['fourth'] = $first;
```

Any idea of regex I could use to match these scenarios?

Comment: can you explain what the problem ? you want when $ inside "" not change ?

Comment: yeah, basically, when there's a php variable being parsed, the script wont replace the double quotes

Comment: What do you expect to happen when `$fourth = "some \"quoted\" value";` is encountered?

Comment: Haven't thought of that one, thanks for reminding me. Ideally it would ignore escaped symbols

Comment: And `$fifth = "It costs $10 today";`? I can list edge cases all day. You are asking to achieve a fool-proof fools-errand.

Comment: Or `$sixth = "A $var which is not declared anywhere so the literal output would have $var with no interpolation";`

Comment: Or `$seventh = "Hi, ${name} how are you?";`

Comment: You're scratching the surface of a turd for no reason. Your only reward is going to be fresh inner turd.

Comment: Could you explain what the final purpose?

Comment: That does make sense, I havent started coding anything related to it so it's just food for thought, it indeed seems like a fool's errand, thanks for enlightening me ^^

Comment: @vovan mostly trying to learn regex while doing something somewhat useful, but I guess there are better ideas out there to help me with that

Comment: If you're just looking to better your regex skills/understanding then just check out various questions and answers at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/regex. If you want to practice your skills in real-time then use https://regex101.com/

Answer (score 0):

You don't need this ".*" because it will match all char.
try this:

```
"([^\$]+)"
```

Comment: This results in catastrophic backtracking. Generally speaking, not a good thing...

Comment: sorry, just remove the "*" on the last part